# Feasibility of Chomping Egg

Tags: biology, creature-design

The 'Chomping Egg' in question is an egg-shaped creature clad in a calcareous shell. It has only two limbs, and those are the tube-like legs, each of which are flexible and end in a suction cup. Its mouth is a toothless hollow inside the head, with the opening being the "teeth"-it's shaped like a natural crack in the eggshell, sort of like a lightning bolt, and the edges of this opening are essentially razor-sharp blades. It has two black eyes set in the top front side of the egg.

Inside the calcareous shell, it has a protective membrane as tough as boar hide let's say, and a gelatinous body. As it eats, it grows, causing it to molt and eat its shell. With each molt and reformation of the shell, its shell grows slightly harder. Eventually, it seals its eyes and mouth closed to form a cocoon, then emerges as a quadruped with its eyes and mouth set in the round end of the "egg".

As for reproduction and excretion, they reproduce sexually and are livebearers, and they have a "close-ended" digestive system, which means they expel waste and everything they can't digest from their mouths (think owl pellets, or perhaps sewage).

Is this creature feasible, and if not, what modifications and adaptations does it need?

Comment: Does this creature also eat ghosts and chomp power pellets?  ᗣ  ᗤ

Comment: Very funny, but it's not Pac-Man. Not sure where you got that, but I'd love to know!

Comment: I googled to see if there was a pac-man UTF character. Stack Exchange didn't let me down: https://superuser.com/questions/194195/is-there-a-pac-man-like-character-in-ascii-or-unicode

Comment: Hold up, why is everyone equating this thing with Pac-Man? Is it the mouth? Also, CaM, that was hilarious.

Comment: Because when I see a "chomping" spheroidal creature, I immediately remember Pac-Man. Especially after the cartoon that later came out, showing he ate literally anything and everything. It's... https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/VideoGame/PacMan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**SURE!**

And as is often the case, Nature beat you to it. Allow me to introduce the [saccorhytus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saccorhytus):

[image: researchgate.net]

Basically exactly what you're looking for: an egg shaped animal that eats and craps from the same orifice. Everything else you describe is either aesthetics or else bits that are well explainable via ordinary evolutionary processes. For example, the "body cones" could well evolve into tube shaped legs, calcareous shells are well known in the animal kingdom, etc.

Comment: I'm honestly amazed that this thing even exists. You're telling me an egg with legs is perfectly possible through this saccorhytus? Wow, just wow.....

Comment: Well, that's what we do here. We make the merely questionable into the wonderfully plausible!