# What Will Be The Implications of Crafting Cubes?

Tags: society, magic

**Background (setting):** My world, Alendyias, is more than a little interesting. As the Fracture in Reality grows and expands, it takes apart and reforms worlds inside itself, and over the ages this has formed one big world: Alendyias. The worlds reform because of three things: 1. gravity pulls the pieces of a world toward each other, 2. Pieces of a world exhibit a magnetic pull, or affinity, to each other; and 3. the destructive energy that fuels the Fracture itself has a reversed creative side; the destruction caused by the Fracture is just a rebirth.

The humans and other sentient races soon realized the potential of the exotic objects and materials they found in their reborn world, which were superior to what they had previously; things like mithril and adamant. And thanks to Rorjon, (see [Role of Druids in Fantasy Society](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/193604/role-of-druids-in-fantasy-society) to find out more about Rorjon) they have Crafting Cubes to use it.

A Crafting Cube is, quite simply, a block of wood infused with creative energy, large enough to fit objects on it and with a grid on one side. They can be any size (as long as they are cut from a piece block of wood and are not made out of multiple pieces of wood), but the size of the objects you can craft on a Crafting Cube is dependent on size; a Cube with a 2'x2' grid can only work on objects if the size of the objects on it (length *and* width) is no more than four feet combined.

Once objects are on a Crafting Cube, you can bend, fuse, and splice them to your heart's content. For example, let's say you have a brick and a stout ax handle on your Cube. If you stick them together, they'll stay stuck together and you'll have a hammer (unless you were weird and arranged them wrong). If you pull the ax handle from opposite sides, it'll split neatly in two. As for the brick, you can mold the brick with your hands, as long as it remains within a foot of the Cube.

Now that I've covered just about everything, my question is: *What Will Be The Implications of Crafting Cubes?*

*Things You Might Want To Consider:*

1. Ease of Engineering-I already know that making armor, metal tools, and weapons will be pretty dang easy thanks to Crafting Cubes. However, Crafting Cubes do *not* allow you to turn rocks into dust, or to get iron out of iron ore, or split compounds like iron sulfide into iron filings and sulfur dust. Precision work will also be difficult *still*; in order to make a protective metal layer on cloth (the fusion between the two leaves the metal flexible as cloth to the wielder and as rigid as regular metal to attacks) one must have good hands.
2. Rarity of Crafting Cubes-Only 1 out of every 7,000 trees exhibits the signs; in other words, only 1 out of 7,000 trees can be used to make Crafting Cubes. These signs are: unusually quick growth, exotic colored and/or multicolored bark and leaves, and unusual structure (twisting or bent trunk and/or branches). This tree will be cut into sections, and those sections will be cut apart to make as many Crafting Cubes as possible.

Comment: if your question is about "What Will Be The Implications of Crafting Cubes?", i think you put wrong title there it say "Implications of Crafting With Monster Drops In a Fantasy Society"

Comment: Oh, _thank you_ for pointing that out! I will fix that right now.

Comment: sooo, a crafting table from minecraft?

Comment: Not quite, but I do admit they are close. Too close you think?

Comment: not too close, but would probably cause some readers/viewers whatever to be like "that's familiar" and "oh like that thing from minecraft!" I wouldn't say your copying it or anything, just that they seem similar

Comment: Okay, I can live with that.

Comment: If things you put on that cube have unusual material properties as long as they stay in there… What is preventing the same to happen to the tissue of the hands of the person using it? I can imagine I put my hand down on one of these cubes, then I try to pull it back, just to have it clean cut, no more hand for me.

Comment: I see your point Theraot, but Crafting Cubes don't affect living things. The _trees_ they come from, on the other hand....

Comment: So... You can lose your nails (and hair)? If yes, I guess that is the price to pay to use these and, I guess the cube is limited to the shapes and quality you can make with modelling clay using no tools. If no, some tools are viable, which opens manufacturing options.