# How Dangerous Are Spikagi?

Tags: medieval, mythical-creatures

If you've seen [How Dangerous Are Ploppers?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/199706/how-dangerous-are-ploppers), you know that only 9 out of 10 Chompers that eat a Plop become a Plopper. This question concerns what happens to the 10th Chomper.

You see, that 10th Chomper doesn't just become an armored Plop or a goopy Chomper or a blob with a toothy maw! No, that would be too easy! Instead, it becomes one of two deadly, bizarre monsters: a Spikagi or Whackagi. This question concerns one thing:

**Spikagi.**

They only come up to a toddler's waist, but they are lethal. The body looks like a cone, with four spikes coming off it for arms and legs; a pair situated just above the bottom, where the legs really should be, and a pair just below the pointy tip. They have two beady eyes and a thin line for a mouth, which can open surprisingly wide-if a Spikagi encountered a sunbather, they could eat them whole, but they’d have a very hard time moving around after that!

Each of their "limbs" is a thick cone that tapers straight down from the middle to form a nice, crisp, *razor-sharp* edge (and straight down from the base to form a deadly point). (Yes, these cones are cones with edges, making them a hybrid of cone and prism.) Basically giant spikes as thick around as a man's thigh at the base, and as long as one of those conical birthday hats, and their body is just a slightly bigger version of these spikes. Spikagi can rotate these spikes 360 degrees, and they move either by spinning sideways (like a wheel spider) or by walking. You'd think they'd fall all the time either way, but no; Spikagi have impeccable balance and can walk across a tightrope without any problem whatsoever.

They have strength and speed equal to the average toddler, a bronze shell as strong as enamel and as tough and sharp as a steel razor, and if that wasn’t enough, they can spring six feet up and six feet away in a single bound. (Obviously, their legs are much stronger than a toddler's, but everything else is about equal.) If you tick one off, they can fire one of their needle-like limbs with the same speed and force as a crossbow.

No, this does not significantly weaken Spikagi, because they are like starfish and can A) seal off the wound immediately upon firing and B) grow the limb back. They do this within two weeks. If they fire all of their spikes, including the central spike, what's left is a core that looks sort of like a d20, upon which is the Spikagi's face. (It's sort of like a skull, held within the shell).

Spikagi can roll at speeds of 30 mph in core form (45 when they have their limbs) and can still jump six feet in a single bound. As a secondary defense, the core has a shell that's every bit as strong and sharp and that of their spikes, which makes their corners and edges downright lethal.

Now, everything above considering, I have to ask: **How Dangerous Are Spikagi?**

**Specifications For Best Answer:**

1. The best answer will analyze the lethality of a Spikagi (its ability to harm or kill medieval Europeans) and its CRD (Capacity to Resist Dying) to determine how dangerous it is. CRD is based off a monster's durability, and how hard it would be for medieval Europeans with medieval weaponry to kill or harm that monster.
2. The best answer will also take the Rarity of Plops and Chompers into account, which have populations akin to rats in the wild. Chompers often eat Plop, just because they are there, and as stated before, 9 out of 10 of those Chompers will become Ploppers while the lucky one left will has a 50/50 shot at becoming a Spikagi.
3. Finally, the best answer will address whether Spikagi actually need flayfire or whether it's just too much. I don't want to be ridiculous, but I'm certain Spikagi need some sort of ranged attack in order to be a credible threat. If I am wrong (if the ranged attack is just too much) the best answer should tell me so and explain why.

Comment: _as tall as the typical dwarf_ Are you referring to humans with dwarfism? If not, could you identify a concrete value? I can't recall the last time I interacted with a group of dwarves (dwarfs?) and a reference may be helpful for answers.

Comment: @Trioxidane: thank you, the question now addresses Spikagi alone.

Comment: @Frostfyre: the average dwarf height (or minimum height to be qualified as a dwarf) is 4 feet 10 inches.

Comment: brainstorming for the ranged attack: maybe they, instead of having acid spit (hard to pull off without wrecking one's mouth, but maybe there's a binary compound that's brutally corrosive when mixed?), when desperate they shoot out their own limbs at  great speed. It does leave them vulnerable afterwards, but not many will be able to pursue after getting a spike to the face.

Comment: @JohnDvorak: great idea, thank you so much! Spikagi were inspired by starfish, and shooting their spike limbs would go great with a starfish's powers of regeneration!

Comment: Can I ask about their conical limbs? You state they are razor sharp and tipped, but true cones are only tipped. Am I right to assume it has an edge also, making it a half cone, half prism-like shape? Also a rough diameter of these limbs would help tremendously to determine its effectivity, and this also depends on if their taper is exponential or straight.

Comment: @Plutian: thank you, I've added some more detail on the spikes. Yes, the spikes are half cone and half prism, being round but with razor-sharp edges and points. I believe the taper is best described straight down from the base.

Comment: Suggested edit :)

Comment: For some non explained things

Comment: "They have strength and speed equal to the average toddler", "they can spring six feet up and six feet away in a single bound" - both of those can't really be true at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

$ \color{orange}{\large \text{Orange Alert} }$

The Spikagi will not walk into a town and turn it into a graveyard. But the town must be prepared.

Medieval farmers can do this. They dig a hole, lure the monster into the hole, then bury it. They dig the holes in advance and always have a 10ft hole ready for the next Spikagi that wanders in.

The monster is not immediately dangerous. A mundane bear, wolf, or feral dog is a bigger threat in the short term. The Spikagi moves slowly and is weaker than a human child. You can walk away from it. You can whack it with a shovel or pitchfork. You can block it by closing a door.

This is only a temporary solution. These things are made of metal and never tire. It can toddle after you for days until you collapse from exhaustion. It can come back every time you whack it. It will slowly wear down the door with its metal blades.

Eventually the Spikagi must be buried. Or it will wear you down.

With enough Spikagis the village will collapse. They spend more time fighting monsters than farming and they starve. This happens extra fast if the monsters attack their livestock.

Built up cities have difficulty with the hole method. You cannot dig a hole in the middle of the town square. Fortunately, built up cities have more money than farming villages. Most of them have unlocked the Adamantite Weapons perk on the Tech Tree. Or they have a Lvl 4 Pugilist in the Town Guard. Either will make short work of a Spikagi.

Cold places have the same difficulty with the hole method. The ground is frozen and hard to dig. Fortunately, Spikagis don't like in cold places. Instead you get Sp-ice-kagis made of ice instead of metal. These are countered using bonfires.

Comment: Cold places have snow, where Spikagis would be stuck promptly. Between seasons they have mud which will do them even quicker.

Comment: @alamar Where I live it is below freezing in the Winter but it rarely snows.

Comment: Then you may have unique problems with Spikagis not shared by the 95% of the world who either have warm winters or wet/snowy ones.