# How Dangerous Are Whackagi?

Tags: mythical-creatures, medieval

The twin of [How Dangerous Are Spikagi?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/200273/how-dangerous-are-spikagi), which concerned Spikagi. This question concerns their big blue twin:

**Whackagi.**

It sounds funny, but it's not. These big blue bruisers are 4 feet 10 inches tall, with an egg-shaped body, two stumpy legs, and two flail-like arms and tail. They have the strength of a gorilla, proportional to their size, and their bodies appear to be made of some sort of blue, vulcanized rubber. This unique aspect of their physiology makes them extremely resistant to cutting, stabbing, or bludgeoning damage, to the point that they are impervious to conventional medieval weaponry (arrows, spears, swords, axes, warhammers, and the like) that hasn’t been specially designed or enchanted to overcome their defenses. Oh, and they're fireproof.

The position of their blobby eyes and frowny mouth reminds one of a frog, and this is actually one of their greatest weapons. You see, with their prehensile tongue and wide gape, they can actually reel in and devour an adult male, much like a giant frog.

They make up for this terrifying ability with their tongue’s length (which reaches up to thirteen feet), their speed (their top speed is 6 m/s, 13.4 mph for those used to that form of measurement, but they can sustain that indefinitely), and their intelligence. They have slightly below average human intelligence, like the stereotypical football jock.

They aren't exactly rare (see ProjectApex's answer to [How Dangerous Are Ploppers?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/199706/how-dangerous-are-ploppers) for why), so Whackagi form "tribes" of 11-22 individuals. These tribes work together well when they're defending themselves or competing against other tribes, but when all is said and done, Whackagi tend to go off and do their own thing. This "thing" is usually looking for fights (or food), fighting other Whackagi, setting stuff on fire (the mages don't know how they do it with flails for arms, but they can and will set things on fire), or setting up massive explosions using black powder they made themselves.

All that considered, I have to ask: **How Dangerous Are Whackagi?**

**Specifications For Best Answer:**

1. The best answer will analyze the lethality of a Whackagi (its ability to harm or kill medieval Europeans) and its CRD (Capacity to Resist Dying) to determine how dangerous it is (to medieval Europeans). CRD is based off a monster's durability, and how hard it would be for medieval Europeans with medieval weaponry (specifically medieval villagers, soldiers, or knights) to kill or harm that monster.
2. The best answer will also take the Rarity of Plops and Chompers into account, which have populations akin to rats in the wild. Chompers often eat Plop, just because they are there, and as stated before, 9 out of 10 of those Chompers will become Ploppers while the lucky one left will have a 50/50 shot at becoming a Whackagi.
3. Finally, the best answer will address whether some aspect of Whackagi makes them ridiculously dangerous or hard to kill. I want them to be a credible threat, but not overwhelmingly dangerous.

Comment: Dangerous for who? A softair bullet is very dangerous for one's eyes but totally armless for a tank.

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica: dangerous for medieval Europeans. Thank you, I've now modified the OP to clarify.

Comment: Why the downvote? Please explain what I need to fix, change, or clarify.

Comment: If they're only slightly less intelligent, on the average, than humans, do they have culture?  A language?  Can one individual who escapes a trap set for it warn others?

Comment: Still too vague. There were thousands of Europeans, and an European toddler is not a European knight

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica: alright, I hope I've cleared it up now.

Comment: `...they can actually reel in and devour an adult male, much like a giant frog.` Adult male _human_, I'm assuming. `They make up for this terrifying ability with their tongue’s length...` that isn't making up for anything; a 13' tongue, is pretty terrifying. Without looking through a dozen other questions, how many tribes of `11-22 individuals` would coexist in a 100-mile radius

Comment: I don't believe there is an objective way to measure how dangerous an animal is, so how is this anything but opinion-based?

Answer (score 1):

There are a fair few vectors missing from your question which could vastly change the direction of this answer, so I am making a few assumptions:

- *They will be fairly rare, and therefore have little to no no pack mentality. Pack tactics of two or more of these monsters would wildly differ from solo encounters.*
- High aggression, always attack when encountering humans. Also tend to wander as they please (this is to ensure encounters happen).
- Just because someone plays football or is a jock, it doesn't mean they have a certain intelligence. But from the way this question is worded I'll assume slightly below average human intelligence, as often depicted commonly in college movies.

**Speed**

Their speed is the most limiting factor to this creature. With a top speed of 1kmh or 0.63 mph, they are extremely slow. With the average human walking speed being roughly 5kmh or 4mph, anyone could walk away from seeing one of these creatures at a more than leisurely pace. With their maximum range being 6 foot or 1.8 meters, one would have to be very unfortunate to get caught within range of this creature.  The only real danger would be if they would be nocturnal and catch people camping outside, or if they were to wander into densely populated urban areas like markets. And even then, after the first one or two victims, the rest would be out of range in no time. When you spot one on the wild (they are very easy to spot at range, as they are blue), all you'd have to do is go around it in a wide arc and mind your business. All in all, with this speed I doubt they will be a credible threat to anyone not directly trying to attack it.

**CRD**

Which brings us to the requested capacity to resist dying. Say one of these does show up in a town, and eats one or two town folk, its safe to say the rest would like to get rid of it. Here is we're the trouble starts, as it is ridiculously resistant to any kind of medieval weaponry, and smart enough to avoid most low effort traps. Of course, due to their speed a town could take hours of not days to prepare for a fight, as keeping anyone away from it would be fairly easy to do. This makes traps like pitfalls efficient, if you disguise it properly and can bait the monster. Once caught, you can take your leisure time finding a way to kill the thing, or simply wait for it to starve.

I would imagine the most effective counter for this monster would be fire. Simply douse it in flammable liquid and set it ablaze. Impervious or not, it will take a tremendous amount of damage. My preferred attack would be to catch it with a fishing net covered in any kind of oil, or to catch it in a pitfall with coal and firewood on the bottom.

**conclusion**

These monsters are massively let down by their speed and range. I doubt it would be a threat to anyone they don't immediately get the drop on, or is stupid enough to attack them with a less than ten foot pole. If anyone did get too close, this would mean near instant death by clobbering or gobbling, but again, it would be really easy not to get close. Given human psychology, if one were spotted in the wild they would alert the nearest town, who would likely make a spectacle out of killing the thing. Bait it, catch it, set it ablaze wile drinking and dancing all night.

Comment: Great answer, I'll edit the OP to make things clearer. Yes, it is right to assume slightly below average human intelligence, that's exactly what I wanted. I'll also extend the range and speed of Whackagi.

Comment: I've edited the OP, not sure what will change.

Comment: Please don't radically change the parameters of your question so that it completely invalidates existing answers. This is considered inappropriate and disrespectful to the effort that may have gone into the existing answers. It's better to rethink your question and ask a new one. See related meta question: https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4403/72352

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't mean to disrespect anyone. Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: No problem, I'm not spiteful :) but your changes completely invalidate my answer, but you wouldn't have made the changes without it. This means I answered your question, and the new one with its parameters should be a new question. It's best to roll back the question to before, and start a new one. You can leave this open to see if anyone answers with something else you might have missed.

Comment: Great, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

Their slow nature is by far their biggest limiting factor and their second most would be their rather striking and obvious appearance. If the creature cannot float I doubt it has the mobility needed to swim and so drowning it would be a rather easy disposal method. the creature from what I understand would have a very hard time actually when it comes to entering any form of walled city so it would most likely only be able to prey on small towns as a sort of ambush predator. if it can climb trees that would be a decent hiding spot but a strong thicket of brush might be enough. I assume their best tactic may be to do night raids for sleeping people and livestock and never leaving too far from the outskirts of town.

Something worth noting is their leather of course! It would be a very useful luxury item if it is as stab an crush resilient as you say. Expect to see high generals and royalty sporting plates of bright rubbery blue on the battle field. If they're highly common than maybe even applications as simple as a blacksmith apron or workers gloves. However if they are rare and their skin is that magnificent expect to see them being hunted rather enthusiastically for the reward they bare that could make any surf quite a decent pay.

Comment: I realized how useful Whackagi leather would be, but your thoughts on it are still very helpful! Your points on drowning and their appearance are also rather good.

Comment: I came up with something else but wasn't really sure where to put it but: they are rubbery in nature and presumably rather bouncy (of course heavy too) but if they are shock absorbent enough then they may be able to effectively slap each other to get the other bouncing for a huge boost in mobility, this of course only working due to their high strength. Getting hit by one moving fast enough would be very dangerous as well.

Comment: YES! That enables them to launch each other!