# Benefits of the Strengthen Enchantment

Tags: magic, humans

The Strengthen Enchantment is gained from [Whackagi](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/200301/how-dangerous-are-whackagi), which makes it kind of difficult to gain, but what happens if someone does? Essentially, my question is **How Will The Strengthen Enchantment Benefit People?**

**1. What Is The Strengthen Enchantment?**

The Strengthen Enchantment, quite simply, strengthens creatures and objects, tripling their strength and durability. Strengthened creatures thus exert three times as much force as they would normally when moving, which of course requires them to be three times as durable.

However, A) the increased strength does not come with increased energy output, the Enchantment takes care of that and B) the Enchantment has reasonable limits.
While the increased durability of a Strengthened creature or object makes them 3x harder to deform, bend, weaken, or break, Strengthened creatures can hear and feel texture, pressure, and temperature just as well as normally. It's just that the body parts necessary to gain this sensory information are harder to break.

If an object or creature with this Enchantment kills another Whackagi, the Strengthen Enchantment is strengthened slightly, and the Enchanted creature or item then hits *five times* harder and is 5x more resistant to damage. The creature's increased strength and resistance is not multiplied by five; rather, it's *original* strength and resistance is multiplied by 5 instead of 3.

If that creature or item then kills a third Whackagi, its effect doubles; the Enchantment holder hits 10x harder and is 10x harder to damage.

**2. How Do You Get It?**

In order to gain a monster's enchantment, you must use one of the following methods:

A. Be Inside It When It's Killed

If a monster eats you and you're still alive when it's killed, you gain its Enchantment and are healed of whatever injury may have resulted from being exposed to the mercies of another's digestive systems.

B. Kill It With Your Own Body

A good example would be Hercules strangling the Nemean Lion. If your body is the weapon used to kill a monster, then you gain its Enchantment. However, there must be *no buffer.* Put in clearer terms, strangling a monster for its Enchantment will do you no good if you're wearing gloves, because the gloves will get Enchanted instead!

One way to do this would be to eat a Whackagi, alive and whole, making your digestive system the weapon that kills the monster. However, the size of a Whackagi should make this impossible, so....

C. Using a Better Weapon

There are two ways to do this. The first is to kill the Whackagi with an weapon incorporating your own body, while the second is to kill a Whackagi with part of another creature and then use A or B on that creature, after it gains the desired Enchantment. (The latter's pedantic, eh?)

The first can be accomplished by simply forging one's nail clippings and/or baby teeth into a sword, then killing a monster with it. This will enchant both you *and* the weapon. The second requires you to take a horn, claw, or fang from a *living creature* and either forge that into a weapon or use the creature part itself as a weapon. Once the Whackagi is killed by this method, you can then use A or B on the unlucky creature to gain the Strengthen Enchantment from it.

**3. Summary:**

So, what would be the benefits of hitting 3, 5, or 10x harder while also being 3-10x harder to bend, break, or deform, for a person in medieval Europe? **Please Note:** For the purposes of answering this question, people with the Strengthen Enchantment have titles. Someone who's killed one Whackagi is a Strongman (or Strongwoman), while someone who's killed two Whackagi is a Strongerman. Someone who's maxed the Enchantment is called a Strongestman, or Strongest for short.

**Specifications For Best Answer:**

1. The best answer will analyze and account for the benefits of Strengthen and determine its potential uses and relevant career paths for those holding it, whether they are Strongest or merely a Strongman.
2. Additionally, as this Enchantment is most likely to affect construction and combat, the best answer will also take into account how Strongmen would affect those areas.

Comment: So, strongestman with predator is a good combo?

Comment: @Writer-of-stories: um, not sure what you mean by "predator." Please explain.

Comment: So the strength gain is an irregular mathematical sequence (3x, then reducing its increase by 2x, then reincreasing by 5x)? Weird, but ok. Note that your question is quite broad per say, and well, you're already giving us the benefits to us; Indeed, being stronger and more resilient are generally seen as strong (:p) points in most imageries along with quite obvious ideal jobs. Well, up to a point (controling your force/never dying issues), and under the condition I understood you correctly.

Comment: @Alendyias The enchantment that lets you get other enchants by only harming the creature, predator.

Answer (score 2):

**Dark and absurd**

Lets take this idea and run into a completely different direction than intended. Let's talk about the psychology of this suicidal enchantment and some absurd possibilities.

**Life worth living**

Finally you strike the final blow to the creature. Your hand plunges against the head with a wet sound and it lies dead at your feet. All sounds seem muted as the enchantment takes effect. You look around. Somehow, everyone is still alive. Except for Jennifer, but you never liked her anyway. Triumphant you stand. A friend brings over the weapon you dropped. Strangely, he's talking but no words seem to form. Only very low sounds seem to reach you. Could it be that the sound can't move or deform the eardrums anymore? Only the lowest noises have an effect, but seem muted. It doesn't matter. You'll be three times as strong and three times as unbreakable! You don't even feel the wind anymore. It can't touch you!

What can touch you is your sexy friend. She's in the mood for a victory shag. She takes you to her tent. But you don't feel the touch of her hand, the feel of her breasts or her long hair on your body. You barely feel a thing. Going outside you want to cool down. But the wind seems absent despite pulling at your clothes. The ground seems unfamiliar. You can barely register if your feet touch the ground even!

A week later and the world seems dull. Barely any sound and no feelings. Basically you can only feel something if it's really strong or yourself. It is living hell! A month, a year... how long before life seems empty and there's no other way out? You've become fat from food and are drawn to art. It's because they're only senses that seem unaffected. Smell, taste and vision. You indulge them to still feel something, to remind tou you're alive. But right after the near soundless world you can barely feel is creeping in.

**The absurd**

You might think to swim, or stand in the rain, or close to a fire. Heat and cold. They'll make me feel something! But at a certain level heat exchange is particles pushing on others. You will feel cold. But only for a moment. The heat escapes your body, but it's three times as potent than normal. The cold touching your body will heat up really quickly. A layer of hotter air above your body can prevent cooling, as there's no more cold to interact with. Heat from outside doesn't bother you, as it needs to work harder to put heat energy in you. But not being able to lose your heat is very dangerous. Any intense activity should be avoided, or there should be supercooling. Likely most of the people with the enchantment will go live further north or on mountain tops without a shirt.

**Strength**

These people will have their life ruined even without using their strength. The moment they get it, you'll have a host of "normal" problems as well. Grab hold of a stick? Or the arm of a friend? You might break it, as you can't feel how hard you squeeze or how much strength you're using. The moment you do feel it, it'll be as if the feeling is muted and far away. Lots in the world will feel like you're holding a strong piece of paper. Maybe you can't always crush it, but you'll hardly feel it.

**Conclusion**

An absurd and dark view, but being 3x stronger and 3x less bendable, breakable or deformable is a recipe for disaster. Most touch cells use pressure to know a touch and how strong it is. Without flexibility and deformation from outside sources it'll reduce the feeling. Hearing is much more affected, as it is relying on a sensitive flexible membrane for many sounds. Cold is the only thing you might still deel, but only shortly. You need to manage your heat and how you interact with the world. Hitting harder and being able to take it 3x as well as normal sounds very beneficial, but likely they'll be dead within a year by their own hand or sit depressed eating whatever comes by. Even worse, not being able to feel yourself walking or talking properly can make both very awkward.

Comment: Thank you, I just put in some necessary clarification.

Comment: [**World made of cardboard speech intensifies**](https://youtu.be/gQabrSpKcJw?t=37)