# Gaining the Strengthen Enchantment

Tags: magic, medieval, low-fantasy

If an item kills a [Whackagi](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/200301/how-dangerous-are-whackagi), then it gains the Strengthen enchantment. The Strengthen Enchantment ups an object or material's rigidity (capacity to hold a shape without deforming), tensile strength, shear resistance, and so forth by 3 times, then 5 times, then 10 times.

In simpler terms, the Strengthen Enchantment makes an item 3x harder to bend, deform, shatter, shear, snap, weaken, or break in any way upon first killing a Whackagi. The second time that same item kills a Whackagi it will become 5x harder to bend, break, or weaken, and the third time that item kills a Whackagi it will become 10x harder to bend, break, or weaken. **Note:** This Enchantment does not increase the weight or mass of an object, just its resistance to damage.

Furthermore, an item with the Strengthen enchantment also multiplies the force put into it by its owner (the person who killed a Whackagi with said item), causing it to hit harder. Great Enchantment, right? There's only one problem. An item or creature must kill a Whackagi to get it. And Whackagi, thanks to their rubbery physiology, are just about invulnerable to medieval weaponry (battleaxes, swords, spears, warhammers) excepting fire.

So, my question is, **How Can A Creature Or Object Gain the Strengthen Enchantment?**

**Specifications:**

1. Gaining the Enchantment: As stated above, an item must kill a Whackagi in order to gain the Strengthen Enchantment. By definition, that means it must inflict lethal damage to a nearly invulnerable monstrosity. The most likely method would be by suffocation or by wielding the item when it is red-hot.

Creatures have it a tiny bit easier; a creature (I'm thinking medieval European here, maybe a dog since they can help fight monsters) can gain the Enchantment by either killing it with their natural weaponry, killing it with a weapon incorporating their own body (like a club studded with baby teeth or a bone steel sword forged with one's own bone), or by being alive inside it when it is killed. As stated in [Unconventional Rebirth: Is It Checked?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/195379/unconventional-rebirth-is-it-checked), gaining the Enchantment naturally heals a creature qualifying for the latter.

2. **A quick list of weaknesses:** Whackagi cannot bend and are therefore made brittle (prone to snapping or shattering) in temperatures below freezing (such as in an icy lake), fire burns them up, and while they have a decentralized nervous system, [this can, in fact, be foiled rather easily](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/199706/how-dangerous-are-ploppers). Crushing or flattening them won't kill them, but the resulting suffocation (from the object on top of them) can and will (since it's rather hard to wriggle out from under something crushing you flat, like a boulder). Finally, Whackagi can breathe underwater, so drowning is out.
3. Answers must be **feasible for medieval Europeans**, something they can not only come up with but actually enact. **The best answer will have the most efficient method(s)**; ie. the method requiring the least time, labor, and resources to enchant an item, human, or dog.

Comment: It is starting to feel that bricks are the ultimate weapons in your world. By the way, do enchantments stack?

Comment: It looks like you're asking how do people in your world kill a monster you've constructed. That seems like a question about stories set in your world rather than asking about how to build the world.

Comment: @Otkin: Yes, enchantments stack, but only to a certain extent. My questions on the benefits of Enchantments (like Quicken and Rubberization) demonstrate this.

Comment: Sounds like it might actually be a drawback on a bow. A bow that is three times as hard to bend would be 3 times as hard to shoot.

Comment: @sphennings: I've posted questions like this before, like Gaining Engorgement for Peasants. If I've miswritten the question, please let me know how to fix it.

Comment: @Yay  It would be a drawback on the bow, but the arrows would certainly benefit.  The problem would be getting a clean kill with an arrow.

Comment: @PaulTIKI getting a clean kill with an arrow would be easier than getting a clean kill with the bow (unless you often beat enemies to death with a bow in melee), but I was just pointing out that it wouldn’t always be an improvement, and that might be useful to add too a story (e.g. the main character spends 2 weeks getting strengthen on a bow and then realizes it’s a downgrade)

Comment: @Yay get close enough and a bow is just a length of wood :)  sounds like a redneck story twist that could be hilarious for non critical characters.  little vignettes of some bumbling fools who keep killing Whackagi in ways that yield nothing at all useful.  a +3 2 ton boulder, a +5 water bucket (they tried it twice) and the enchanted 6 foot Log!

Comment: @PaulTIKI yep, that’s what I was thinking too. Though, it might work on main characters too if you want to add in some comedy.

Comment: This seems to answer itself within the post (i.e. do what a dog does). What is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sharpen Enchantment**

Mundane weapons used by mundane people cannot kill a Whackagi. But [Sharpened](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/200273/how-dangerous-are-spikagi) weapons do the trick. Now getting the Sharpen enchantment is still hard to do, since you have to kill a Spikagi. However a Spikagi is smaller than a Whackagi, with only a hard shell rather than rubberised flesh. So it can be killed with a big hammer on a stick.

Usually these hammers have swords on the reverse end. These swords make swinging the hammer more difficult. However after the kill, the hammer and sword get the Sharpen effect. They can then be separated and you have a Sharpened sword.

**Mid Level Fighter**

A mid-level fighter can hit ten times harder than a normal human, hard enough to kill a Whackagi using mundane weapons. Killing monsters and selling the enchanted weapons is a major income source for mid-level adventurers. The stronger the fighter the more things they can enchant. Lvl 50 fighters stick to axes and swords and such. Lvl 100 fighters can do jewelery and needles and pillowcases.

Note high-level fighters can do this even better. But those guys are usually too expensive or too busy battling dragons in outer-space.

Comment: Or a sharpened mid-level fighter. THIS HAND OF MINE SHTWINGS WITH A AWESOME SHARPNESS!

Answer (score 2):

Well, the methodology is fairly simple.

First, build a Whackagi Trap.  The goal is not to kill them, merely to contain them.   Try a big deadfall trap to squish them and hold them between two big boulders.  tie the boulders together and haul the Whackagi sandwich to an Ice House for holding until the depths of winter.  Or use a pit trap with a tight fitting lid.  You just need something that can capture and hold the Whackagi.

Then, in the coldest part of winter, prep the weapons you want to enchant.  I suspect that Axes, War Hammers, and Maces are going to be the favorites for what is coming next.  A bit before dawn, when the Whackagi is at it's most fragile, Take the weapon and shatter the beast, thoroughly destroying it.  Then take the next captured beast and next weapon, and repeat.  Keep doing this until you run out of beasts or weapons.  Put the newly enchanted weapons in the rack for next year.  Then you can get the next round of enchantments the next winter, after you have captured some more Whackagi.

Why Axes and War Hammers and not Swords?  Well, those weapons tend to be more robust and less prone to breaking when destroying the frozen Whackagi.  A sword could theoretically survive, but might take damage, pick up a bend, or even outright shatter.  So you will want to consider this when going through the enchantment process.  If you want a good representation of what could happen to a blade when Chopping into and shattering ice, watch a few episodes of the show "Forged in Fire"

Answer (score 0):

People highly appreciate high-quality weapons. So best **craftsman would pay for *still alive* Whackagi**. It's no matter who will bring it: hunters from forest or farmers from hatchery. Craftsmen also don't care about the how this victim to be prepared to death. Really great armorers could strengthen even cuirass, helmet or even shoulder pad. But **don't ask how they do it: it's a secret**.

Really rich people could order table, door and other furnishings. There are rumors that **furniture makers just drop pack of new items to Whackagi** and then sell one item at cost of whole pack. But knowledgeable people never say the secret of their profession.
The same about strengthened clothes. Only aristocrats could buy such items and nobody knows how many (and how) Whackagi has been died for queen's dress. And queen don't want to think about death related to her coverlet. So **don't ask if you value your life**.

People say `if you find out the way how items are strengthened then you'll die the same death`. And this death is much harder than just [breaking wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breaking_wheel) or [impalement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impalement). Others say that **any kind of torture originates from some strengthening method** [for some item].

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. . . .