# What Uses Will Chompers Have In Medieval Society?

Tags: mythical-creatures, medieval, low-fantasy

This overdue question concerns Chompers, which are adequately explained in [this link](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/197028/how-can-i-protect-medieval-villages-from-chompers). As a general rule, humanity either eliminates species or finds a use for them, and so I have to wonder what humans will make of one of the most common monster species in my setting. In other words, I'm asking what uses Chompers would have for humans, or what role they'd have in human villages.

Yes, I know; "but Alendyias, you have no idea if people will even domesticate Chompers!" Not so fast, naysayers; we sort-of domesticated cats, and why did that happen? Because they dealt with mice. The same will (most likely) happen for Chompers, mostly because [Plop](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/196649/how-can-i-protect-medieval-villages-from-plops?noredirect=1&lq=1) suck for crops, except that I can see humans taking great pains to succeed with Chompers where they failed with cats (Chompers spit acid and are likely man-eaters, so it's prudent of humanity to ensure proper control of them).

However, humanity *can and will* utilize a creature's nature and physiology, breeding as necessary to enhance desired traits, to fulfill their purposes. Just look at dogs; we took advantage of their pack instinct for companionship and protection, as well as using the same to ensure their obedience when we want them to do something (aid in hunting, herd livestock, pull a cart).

**Defining Edible:** Chompers have the same broad diet as cockroaches, meaning they can eat other animal's waste products. However, Chompers are also intelligent, meaning they'll pick easier meals whenever possible, and they prefer sweet and savory flavors in their food (which naturally leads to a high-energy, high-protein diet).

With this human tendency in mind, my question is **What Uses Will Chompers Have In Medieval Society?**

**Specifications:**

1. The best answer will take into account a Chomper's natural abilities/physiology and determine potential uses for a human who owns a Chomper. Chompers are as intelligent as ravens, which were used for espionage in Cold War America, they can spit acid and climb walls, and of course they're great for dealing with anything edible, as they grow by eating things.
2. The best answer will go off of #1 to determine how useful Chompers will be overall, or in other words, how much they can contribute.

Comment: Please define edible, what I can eat without poisoning myself differs greatly from what most humans can manage and we're the same species. What many birds get away with makes anything a person can eat look positively bland.

Comment: @Ash: great point, thank you! I have now defined edible.

Answer (score 2):

If they produce acid in sufficient quantities that they can afford to spit it up that production is worth something. The alchemists are going to breed them for that product, not necessarily a domesticated strain though. The blood harvest of [Horseshoe Crabs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horseshoe_crab) or milking wild caught snakes to make [antivenom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antivenom) might be analogous situations as to the use of Chompers in this case.

If they had natural pack instincts that could be exploited, like canines, true domestication would make sense for the same roles we use dogs for, guard and hunting companion. They appear however to be solitary and voracious hunters. As you pointed out solitary predators like cats are impossible to fully domesticate, at best they can be taught to tolerate humans in exchange for food. The apparent dangers, and associated property damage, of keeping Chompers would seem to render such an exchange too lopsided to be worthwhile. The only way such a deal would be worthwhile is if Chompers had a preferential prey type that is *more* of a threat and you have indicated that they'll eat anything so that's off the table too.

Answer (score 2):

One general rule for any attempt to perform genocide on (or introducing a foreign invasive species to) an ecosystem is that many other (including humans) species are impacted by that change.

In the case of native species, they will prey on and be the natural prey of other native species. So chompers may keep the population down of Wompums, which in large numbers will eat all human grown foods. And Chompers may also be the favorite food of local wyverns, who if they are eliminated will start eating humans and their livestock.

I recommend reading the Janet Kagen novel 'Mirabella' (1991) for a fun look at problems with messing with fictional ecosystems.

Comment: Thanks for your perspective, I didn't realize the ecological aspect!

Answer (score 1):

Chompers could act as guard animals. They could be trained to recognise family members and attack intruders, like geese. They might also be used for controlling general pest such as mice, like cats. Maybe part of them is even a delicacy in some places.

If they are domesticated, some varieties may eventually be trained/evolve not to eat humans, and/or not to eat some kinds of fencing material such as wood. Then they will deny food sources to wild Chompers near settlements (like feeding scraps to dogs so as not to attract mice).

Comment: These are some great points, I appreciate your perspective! However, wouldn't there be some trait (or traits) Chompers _must_ have to serve as guard animals? What would those be?